# Writing bullet character using java pdfbox 2.0.2

Tags: java, encoding, pdfbox

I am creating pdf document using pdfbox library version 2.0.2
How to write bullet character in pdf
Is EncodingManager class removed from version 2 as I cannot find it with 2.0.2 jar

Also is it possible to write bullet character that are available in MS Word for example
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this:

```
    stream.setFont(PDType1Font.HELVETICA, 12);
    stream.showText("\u2022"); // bullet
    stream.setFont(PDType1Font.ZAPF_DINGBATS, 12);
    stream.showText("\u27A2"); // three-d top-lighted rightwards arrowhead
```

However the "three-d top-lighted rightwards arrowhead" will only be available from PDFBox version 2.0.3 upwards. It has not yet been released, but you can test it from here:
https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfbox-app/2.0.3-SNAPSHOT/

(In theory, the second character should also work with the wingdings font by using `PDType0Font.load`, but it doesn't)

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Any idea when 2.0.3 will be released?

Comment: I assume it will be released within 1-3 months.